# Class function not accepting self. variable

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create a function in a class for rotating rotors in an Enigma machine. However, when I try to tell it which rotor to use it does not accept it, as demonstrated in the code below:

```
from collections import deque

class Rotors:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = deque("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
        self.vi = deque("JPGVOUMFYQBENHZRDKASXLICTW")
        self.vii = deque("NZJHGRCXMYSWBOUFAIVLPEKQDT")           
        self.viii = deque("FKQHTLXOCBJSPDZRAMEWNIUYGV") 
        self.rotor_vi = [self.a, self.vi]
        self.rotor_vii = [self.a, self.vii]
        self.rotor_viii = [self.a, self.viii]
        self.rotors = [self.rotor_vi, self.rotor_vii, self.rotor_viii]
        self.reflector = deque("FVPJIAOYEDRZXWGCTKUQSBNMHL")


    def rotate_rotor(self, rotor):
        rotor.rotate(1)

x = Rotors()
x.rotate_rotor(self.vi)
```

Which gives an output of:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Programs\Enigma.py", line 20, in <module>
    x.rotate_rotor(self.vi)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: `self` doesn't exist **outside** the class methods...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x.rotate_rotor(self.vi)
```

should be:

```
x.rotate_rotor(x.vi)
```